# Saving and Loading Data Structure Items

Tags: vb.net, console, structure

I am quite new to VB.NET and I am attempting to create a console application that can write, save, load and edit sets of data.

Lets say I have something like this:

```
Imports System
Module Module1

    Public Structure EMPLOYEE
        Dim Firstname As String
        Dim Middlename As String
        Dim Lastname As String
        Dim ID As String
    End Structure

    Sub Main()
        Dim John As New EMPLOYEE
        John.Firstname = "John"
        John.Middlename = vbNullString
        John.Lastname = "Smith"
        John.ID = "000230"
    End Sub

End Module
```

What I want to do is to save information into a file that can later be read and formatted into the EMPLOYEE structure, the problem is I have no clue how to do so. I figured I might save it into a formatted .txt like so:

```
000230.txt
FIRSTNAME=John
MIDDLENAME=
LASTNAME=Smith
ID=000230
```

However, I have no idea how to load the data so I can manipulate it in the EMPLOYEE structure system. Help please?

I am not sure if I have made my question clear enough, for as you can see I'm quite new to programming and am not essentially familiar with the terms of speech. Please ask if there's anything I haven't made clear, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

save:

```
Dim objStreamWriter As StreamWriter
objStreamWriter = New StreamWriter("C:\" & John.ID & ".txt")
objStreamWriter.WriteLine("FIRSTNAME=" & John.Firstname & vbcrlf & "Lastname=" & John.Lastname )
objStreamWriter.Close()
```

use System.IO and System.text

Comment: You should initialise a variable during its declaration, not after. Better yet, use a `Using` block to make this code exception safe.

Comment: Can you give an example of the said method? Also, NikoMman, I read the code. It seems to just write a txt file. I wish to read the text file and retrieve the data as a structure item so I can edit it using John.FirstName= something method.